# Change fontsizes and distances between 2 lines

Tags: lyx, fontsize, lyx-layouts

I have a problem with my fontsizes. I want to change the fontsize of my titles globally in my Latex document. I therefore created a newcommand. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[BCOR=8mm,DIV=12,11pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{ifthen} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\titel}[2]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}{}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}{
\begin{center}  \textbf{\fontsize{60pt}{25pt}\selectfont #1} \normalfont\vspace*{-2ex} \end{center}}
{
\begin{center}  \textbf{\fontsize{60pt}{25pt}\selectfont #1} \normalfont\vspace*{-2ex} \end{center} 
\begin{center} \textbf{\huge --- \\ \Huge #2}\end{center}}}}

\titel{I want the 2 linesof this title to be more seperated}{such that the letters aren't that close.}
\end{document}
```

Now the titles are huge, but if the title is separated into 2 lines, then the distance between the title lines is too small such that the letters touch each other.

I just want to have a bigger distance between the two lines. And I don't want to do it via

```
part 1 of the title \\ part 2 of the title
```

in the title command as it then influences the headlines (see command `\kopftitle`)

I am grateful for help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three issues with your code. First, LaTeX's default font family (Computer Modern) doesn't provide a font size of `60pt`; fix this by loading a font family (such as Latin Modern) that does provide this font size. Second, the instruction `\fontsize{x}{y}\selectfont` should come *before* the `\textbf` instruction. Finally, the second argument of `\fontsize` should be larger than the first; for many font families, it's customary to let the so-called baseline skip be about 10 to 20 percent larger than the nominal size of the font.

With these comments factored in, here's the output of your MWE. (Note that I've set the baselineskip to be 10 percent larger than the font size in the title lines. You will probably want to fiddle with this parameter.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[BCOR=8mm,DIV=12,11pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2,float,ifthen}
\usepackage{lmodern}% choose a font family that suits your needs

\newcommand{\titel}[2]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}{}{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}{%
      \begin{center}  
         \fontsize{60pt}{66pt}\selectfont \textbf{#1}   
      \end{center}}
      {\begin{center}  
         \fontsize{60pt}{66pt}\selectfont \textbf{#1} 
       \end{center} 
       \begin{center} \textbf{\huge --- \\  \Huge #2 \\ \null}
       \end{center}%
      }
   }
}

\begin{document}
\titel{I want the lines of this title to be more separated}{so that the letters aren't too close.}

\noindent
And here's some text set in ``normal'' font size (11 pionts)\dots
\end{document}
```